# Sharing same AJAX call for different sets of display logic

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am populating divs with json but I don't think I am doing it the best way. Seems like alot of code and some it seems like it could share.

```
//data for DOM
$.getJSON('json/device.json', function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data[0].attributes, function (key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + '  ' + val + '</li>');
    });

    $('<ol/>', {
        'class': 'raw-list',
        html: items.join('')
    }).hide().fadeIn().appendTo('.json');
});

$.getJSON('json/device.json', function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data[0].status, function (key, val) {
        items.push(val);
    });

    $('<span/>', {
        'class': 'sort-label error',
        html: items.join('')
    }).hide().fadeIn().appendTo('.status-input .sort-label');
});

$.getJSON('json/device.json', function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data[0].location, function (key, val) {
        items.push(val);
    });

    $('<span/>', {
        'class': 'sort-label',
        html: items.join('')
    }).hide().fadeIn().appendTo('.location-input .sort-label');
});

$.getJSON('json/device.json', function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data[0].type, function (key, val) {
        items.push(val);
    });

    $('<span/>', {
        'class': 'sort-label',
        html: items.join('')
    }).hide().fadeIn().appendTo('.type-input .sort-label');
});

$.getJSON('json/device.json', function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data[0].brand, function (key, val) {
        items.push(val);
    });

    $('<span/>', {
        'class': 'sort-label',
        html: items.join('')
    }).hide().fadeIn().appendTo('.brand-input .sort-label');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need multiple `$.getJSON` calls if you're retrieving the same data every time.

For example:

```
$.getJSON('json/device.json', function(data) {

  // First set of display logic
  var items = [];
  $.each(data[0].attributes, function (key, val) {
     items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + '  ' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ol/>', {
    'class': 'raw-list',
    html: items.join('')
  })
  .hide().fadeIn().appendTo('.json');

  // Second set of display logic
  var items = [];
  $.each(data[0].status, function (key, val) {
    items.push(val);
  });

  $('<span/>', {
    'class': 'sort-label error',
    html: items.join('')
  })
  .hide().fadeIn().appendTo('.status-input .sort-label');

});
```

Since you're using a similar block of code for the display logic of most of the data sets, you could wrap this into a function:

```
function displaySortLabel(items, parentClass) {
  $('<span/>', {
    'class': 'sort-label',
    html: items.join('')
  }).hide().fadeIn().appendTo('.' + parentClass +' .sort-label');
}
```

And then call it by:

```
displaySortLabel(items, "location-input");
```